# SQL Server : While Loop using Cursor and exporting XML file

Tags: sql-server, database

Below I am showing what I have try so far.

I have a SQL Server `while` loop using a cursor. The problem in my query is on the line with the code below:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM TRDR 
WHERE TRDR = MyCursor.TRDR
```

I am not sure on how to take the value from the cursor `@MyCursor`

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField INT;
DECLARE @FromDate DATE;
DECLARE @ToDate DATE;
DECLARE @Serie INT;
DECLARE @Sosource INT;
DECLARE @trdr INT;

SET @FromDate = '20160901';
SET @ToDate = '20160930';
SET @Serie = 4700;
SET @Sosource = 1416;
SET @trdr = 2835;

BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT TOP 1000 FINDOC, TRDR 
        FROM FINDOC
        WHERE SOSOURCE = @Sosource 
          AND TRNDATE >= @FromDate 
          AND TRNDATE <= @ToDate 
          AND SERIES = @Serie 
          AND TRDR = 2835
END

OPEN @MyCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @MyField

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT NAME 
    FROM TRDR 
    WHERE TRDR = MyCursor.TRDR
    FOR XML PATH('GrpHdr'), ROOT ('CstmrCdtTrfInitn')

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @MyField 
END; 

CLOSE @MyCursor ;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
```

The Expected output it should be as below:

```
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
   <GrpHdr>
       <name>Chris</name>
   </GrpHdr>
   <GrpHdr>
       <name>Martin</name>
   </GrpHdr>
   <GrpHdr>
       <name>John</name>
   </GrpHdr>
   <GrpHdr>
       <name>George</name>
   </GrpHdr>
   <GrpHdr>
       <name>Michael</name>
   </GrpHdr>
</CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to what you really want for results. Try this and see if this works.

```
   Select TOP 1000 T.Name
            FROM FINDOC F
            JOIN TRDR T ON F.TRDR = T.TRDR
            WHERE F.SOSOURCE = @Sosource 
              AND F.TRNDATE >= @FromDate 
              AND F.TRNDATE <= @ToDate 
              AND F.SERIES = @Serie 
              AND F.TRDR = 2835 
        FOR XML PATH('GrpHdr'), ROOT ('CstmrCdtTrfInitn')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That fix my problem but it create many XML files. Is it possible to create only one XML file?

Comment: Can you show your data, both input and expected results?

Comment: I have add the expected output in my question

Comment: Update answer based on what you want. I don't think you need a cursor for this.